# Extract unique lines by pattern

Tags: regex, bash, unix

wish to ask bash regex question. I need to print unique lines from the list.
This list contains emails and some of them repeated many times and also some of them have same id and password but different mail accounts.

The list looks as follows:

```
firstman@gmail.com:pass1234
someguy@yahoo.com:onepass789
secondman@gmail.com:looksPass
firstman@yahoo.com:pass1234
thirdman@cox.net:mypas345
someguy@mail.com:onepass789
```

`firstman@` `someguy@` repeated 2 times but with other mail providers.

I need to get following output:

```
firstman@gmail.com:pass1234
someguy@yahoo.com:onepass789
secondman@gmail.com:looksPass
thirdman@cox.net:mypas345
```

`uniq -u` do this job just partly - it compares full line, instead i need to compare strings outside of `@emailprovider:` pattern.

How to "discard" this pattern while extracting unique lines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With AWK you can say:

```
awk -F'[@:]' '!seen[$1,$3]++' inputlist
```

yields:

```
firstman@gmail.com:pass1234
someguy@yahoo.com:onepass789
secondman@gmail.com:looksPass
thirdman@cox.net:mypas345
```

- `-F'[@:]'` sets the field separator to either "@" or ":".
- Then `$1` holds the string before "@" and `$3` does after ":".
- The condition `'!seen[$1,$3]++'` tells AWK to print the line if the `$1,$3` entry is not seen.

Comment: It works as expected.And i accepted your answer because i clearly got awk syntax, thanks for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you flip the fields around you can use `--skip-fields=1` (or `-f 1`) to only consider the emails for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `awk` command instead:

```
awk -F@ '!s[$1]{s[$1]=1;print}' filename
```

Comment: Got same output as solution from @tshiono.